# how to reduce process speed of Entity FrameWork code?

Tags: entity-framework-4, webforms

I used this code in order to Read & Update a value in database which indicate Pageviews of a website.

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    intPageView++;
    Session.Add("Online", intPageView);
    DataLayer.MainFunction.UpdateOnlineUser();
}

    public static void UpdateOnlineUser()
    {
        try
        {
            int intCount = 0;
            TaffyPetEntities db = new TaffyPetEntities();
            T_Setting t_s = db.T_Setting.SingleOrDefault(i => i.ID == 1);
            intCount = Convert.ToInt32(t_s.Page_counter);
            intCount++;
            t_s = new T_Setting();
            t_s = db.T_Setting.First(i => i.ID == 1);
            t_s.Page_counter = intCount;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            DataLayer.Error.RegisterError("MainFunction.cs", err.Message);
        }
    }
```

in local system every thing was good also running speed was good, but when website published and uploaded on the server every thing is changed. The problem is, at the first we haven't any data outout and when you clicked on each link on the website it takes too long to show another page. 
to find out problem, i used **Performance Analysis** of VIsual Studio. at the result page of this analysis i found that this part of above code use 70% of total process:
    `T_Setting t_s = db.T_Setting.SingleOrDefault(i => i.ID == 1);`

The questions is: 
1. Is it correct syntax for fetching data in Entity FrameWork at the Data Layer (DAL) of a website?
2. Can i change this code with another method in order to reduce process speed?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but `SingleOrDefault` is going to go through the entire data set to make sure that there is only one element that matches the criteria, whereas `FirstOrDefault` might be first because it's going to return the first match.

Comment: Thank you SOfanatic. in a few articles about EF I saw that They used `SingleOrDefault`. But I changed it to `FirstOrDefault` and nothing happened. this two method seems are same, because again i got 69% of process.